# How to add a widget each time i enter game screen?

Tags: python, widget, screen, kivy

I have a FloatLayout "DiceMazeGame" that contains my game.

I have two screens (menu and game) and i want to add DiceMazeGame to the game screen each time i enter it (from the menu screen).

The game needs to reset itself each time i go from menu screen to game screen.

main.py

```
class DiceMazeGame(FloatLayout):
     #init
     #some functions

class MenuScreen(Screen):
     pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
     pass
```

dicemaze.kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: NoTransition()
    MenuScreen:
        name:"menu"
    GameScreen:
        name:"game"

<MenuScreen>:
    Button:
        on_press: root.manager.current = "game"
        text: "Play !"

<DiceMazeGame>:
    # Widgets
```

My code only adds DiceMazeGame once to the screen. How to add it each time i enter game screen?

```
class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.on_pre_enter(self.clear_widgets())
        self.on_pre_enter(self.add_widget(DiceMazeGame()))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do i add (reset) "DiceMazeGame" to the game screen each time i enter it?
In my code i can only add "DiceMazeGame" once, i added the code to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite `on_pre_enter` method, not use it once in init:

```
class GameScreen(Screen):

    # overwrite on_pre_enter method
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.add_widget(DiceMazeGame())

    # overwrite on_leave method - optional
    def on_leave(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
```